# Convert xml file to LMDB file for caffe

Tags: python, c++, xml, deep-learning, caffe

I want to use feature vectors which have been extracted from training image dataset as an input for caffe convolutional neural network. The feature vectors have been saved in xml file. 
I'm really new in caffe I want know how can I convert xml file to LMDB as an caffe input and how to mention in the model that I'm using feature vectors instead of images.
the xml file is :
[image]

Comment: in what format are the features saved in `xml` what is the schema?

Comment: do you know how to parse XML in C++?

Comment: no I don't know how to parse xml file in c++, it's my first time that using xml file.

Comment: any chance you can work in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use python, then it should be quite easy for you.

First, you need to parse the XML file and read the data into a numpy array.
You can do this using [xml python package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

The second stage is to write the data you have in numpy array into lmdb.
You can use [this solution](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) to write LMDB using python.

Regarding caffe, as long as your input data is in order, caffe does not care if it works on images, feature vectors or any other input.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. But I decided to change my code and save the feature descriptors in HDF5 format to make it easier to read.

Comment: @ga97rasl HDF5 is indeed a good choice. Have you looked into `"HDF5Data"` input layer in caffe?

Comment: I read the [Caffe tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) about data layers. But I didn't implemented yet.

Comment: I've tried hdf5 format but then I figured out that it's not good because it takes too much memory due to large number of input images. Then I tried to follow your tips. But I don't know how to parse the xml file in python. my xml file does not have any child tag. could you please help me with more detail. thanks

Comment: @ga97rasl you know you can split hdf5 input into several files for caffe?

Comment: No I don't know. But I don't understand how splitting to several files will help me?

Comment: @ga97rasl you said hdf5 is "not good because it takes too much memory due to large number of input images". So, if you can split the input data into several smaller hdf5 files you should be good to go.